# Materialize Autocomplete não carrega valores

Tags: javascript, jquery, data, materialize

Estou tendo problemas para carregar valores no autocomplete do Materialize. O que ocorre é o seguinte:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#sel_estado').change(function() {
      $.post('auto_cid.php', {id_estado:$('#sel_estado').val()}, function(res){
    console.log(res);
    $('#auto_cida').autocomplete({
        source:res,
        limit:5,
        minLenght:1
    });

    });
  });
```

Retorno do post é este:

```
{"Acrelândia": null,"Assis Brasil": null,"Brasiléia": null,"Bujari": null,"Capixaba": null,"Cruzeiro do Sul": null,"Epitaciolândia": null,"Feijó": null,"Jordão": null,"Mâncio Lima": null,"Manoel Urbano": null,"Marechal Thaumaturgo": null,"Plácido de Castro": null,"Porto Acre": null,"Porto Walter": null,"Rio Branco": null,"Rodrigues Alves": null,"Santa Rosa do Purus": null,"Sena Madureira": null,"Senador Guiomard": null,"Tarauacá": null,"Xapuri": null}
```

Se eu pegar o retorno, copiar e colar dentro do **data:**, funciona perfeitamente.

Agora, gostaria de saber como fazer para que o bendidto do data: ou o source: carregue diretamente estes valores do retorno. O que estou faznedo de errado? =(

Alguma ideia?

Codigo da página com os scripts

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
<div class="input-field col s12 m12">
    <select id="sel_estado" name="sel_estado">
        <option disabled selected>Selecione UF </option>
        <?php
          $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id,nome FROM tvo_estado ORDER BY nome');
          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
          foreach($result as $estado){
              echo '<option value="'. $estado['id'] .'">'. $estado['nome'] .'</option>';
          }
        ?>
    </select>
    <label>Estado</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12 m12">
  <select id="sel_cidade" name="sel_cidade">
    <option disabled selected>Selecione Cidade </option>
  </select>
  <label>Cidade</label>

  <input type="text" name="auto_cida" id="auto_cida" class="autocomplete">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

<!-- Habilita Menu Planos -->
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#sel_estado').formSelect();
$('#sel_cidade').formSelect();
});

$().ready(function() {
$('#sel_estado').change(function() {

  $.post('sel_cidade.php', {id_estado:$('#sel_estado').val()}, function(data){
    $.each(data, function (index, value){
        $("#sel_cidade").append("<option value=" + value.id + '">' + value.nome + '</option>');
    });
    $('#sel_cidade').formSelect();
    }, 'json');
  });

  $.post('auto_cid.php', {id_estado:$('#sel_estado').val()}, function(res){
    console.log(res);
    $('#auto_cida').autocomplete({
        source:res, //source:res ou data:res que nao muda nada copy+paste = ok
        limit:5,
        minLenght:1
    });

    });
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Print da inspeção do Navegador]

Código para realizar o retorno das informações é

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,nome from tvo_cidade where id_estado="'. $id .'" ORDER BY nome ASC');
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
      $x=0;
      $aux="{";
      foreach ($result as $lines) {
           $aux .= "\"". $lines['nome'] ."\": null";
           if($x<sizeof($result)-1){
             $aux .=",";
             $x++;
           }else{
             $aux .='}';
           }
      }
      echo json_encode($aux);
```

MAs tmb já utilizei o mesmo que uso para retornar as cidades que carrego no menu encadeado (que está funcionando) que é este trecho (mas que tmb nao funciona para o autocomplete):

```
if($id){
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,nome from tvo_cidade where id_estado="'. $id .'" ORDER BY nome ASC');
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
      echo json_encode($result);
      return;
    }
```

Na esperança de uma solução... ='( 
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no formato do atributo `data`, ele não é uma lista, é um objeto com os valores definidos como `"texto exibido: url para ícone"`, conforme a documentação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode usar `null` como segundo parâmetro para mostrar apenas o texto, sem um ícone.

O retorno do `post` deveria ser:

```
{
    "Acrelândia" :null,
    "Assis Brasil":null,
    "Brasiléia":null,
    "Bujari":null,
    "Capixaba":null,
    "Cruzeiro do Sul":null,
    "Epitaciolândia":null,
    "Feijó":null,
    "Jordão":null,
    "Mâncio Lima":null,
    "Manoel Urbano":null,
    "Marechal Thaumaturgo":null,
    "Plácido de Castro":null,
    "Porto Acre":null,
    "Porto Walter":null,
    "Rio Branco":null,
    "Rodrigues Alves":null,
    "Santa Rosa do Purus":null,
    "Sena Madureira":null, 
    "Senador Guiomard":null, 
    "Tarauacá": null,
    "Xapuri": null
  }
```

---

Abaixo um exemplo funcional do autocomplete:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: {
        "Acrelândia" :null,
        "Assis Brasil":null,
        "Brasiléia":null,
        "Bujari":null,
        "Capixaba":null,
        "Cruzeiro do Sul":null,
        "Epitaciolândia":null,
        "Feijó":null,
        "Jordão":null,
        "Mâncio Lima":null,
        "Manoel Urbano":null,
        "Marechal Thaumaturgo":null,
        "Plácido de Castro":null,
        "Porto Acre":null,
        "Porto Walter":null,
        "Rio Branco":null,
        "Rodrigues Alves":null,
        "Santa Rosa do Purus":null,
        "Sena Madureira":null, 
        "Senador Guiomard":null, 
        "Tarauacá": null,
        "Xapuri": null
      },
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

## Edit

Não sei como está fazendo para retornar o conteúdo, o [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) pode estar detectando como [texto](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), tente adicionar `"json"` como último argumento do `$.post()`

Ficaria assim:

```
$.post('auto_cid.php', {id_estado:$('#sel_estado').val()}, function(res) {
    $('#auto_cida').autocomplete({
        source:res,
        limit:5,
        minLenght:1
    });
}, "json");//Aqui é o tipo de conteúdo retornado, por padrão ele tenta adivinhar, mas pode acabar reconhecendo incorretamente
```

Comment: Olá Denis, obrigado pela resposta!
Eu fiz esse teste e funcionou, porém nao consigo fazer com que o retorno seja neste formato. 
Como eu poderia fazer para obter esse retorno num formato que o autcomplete consiga "ler" as informações, como no caso do menu de cidades?
Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Consegui gerar um retorno exatamente como pede o objeto, mas nao sei por que cargas d'água nao carrega os valores. 

Se eu colocar um console.log(retorno), pegar a saida e colar no data: funciona perfeitamente. saberia me explicar por que colocando data: retorno ou source:retono isso nao acontece ?

Obrigado

Comment: Adiciona na pergunta como está seu código, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Salve Denis, atualizei a pergunta, veja se ajuda.. obrigado!

Comment: Consegue colocar toda a página? Acho que o problema é com carregamento de script, consegue colocar também o que é retornado no console?

Comment: Denis, o retorno que eu coloquei é do post tanto via console quanto via php echo.
Se eu simplesmente copia e colar a saida (console ou echo) dentro da script data:{...} funciona normal. Acho que isso descarta o erro de carregamento do script.  MAs... de qualquer forma, vou colocar aqui uma versao simplificada da pagina + retorno (console)... 1 min

Comment: Atualizado Denis... veja se ajudou... Obrigado.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, dá uma olhada lá

Comment: Olá Denis, Não funcionou tmb.... to quase desistindo... Obrigado pela ajuda..

Answer (score 0):

Fala Bruno, blz?

Eu acho que no retorno está chegando uma string e precisa transformar em um JSON... tenta usar o JSON.parse();

Faz assim:

```
$.post('auto_cid.php', {id_estado:$('#sel_estado').val()}, function(res){

res = JSON.parse(res);
console.log(res);

$('#auto_cida').autocomplete({
    source:res, //source:res ou data:res que nao muda nada copy+paste = ok
    limit:5,
    minLenght:1
});

});
```

Comment: SAlve Guilherme, Nao funcionou tmb.. tá um mistério isso, mas obrigado pela tentativa hehe... abração cara !